# How can I create a custom coercion for my Reform form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reform

I have a form created with Reform gem.

I have a variable that is an array of ids, so the task in to update this variable to be filled with objects from DB.

How can I create custom coercion with dry-types to perform this?
I did not find examples of custom types in documentaion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reform can use dry-type coercion. This will over-ride the setter, coerce the value and call the original setter. You don't have to create a custom coercion for your use case. See the example below.

Include following gem in your Gemfile

```
gem 'dry-types'
```

Code below goes into your form class say form.rb

```
require 'reform/form/coercion'
class Form < Reform::Form
  property :ids, type:Types::Coercible::Array.member(Types::Form::Int)
end
```